# Spanning Tree Protocol

Tags: networking

I have a little doubt in spanning tree listening states.

In listening state switch can not learn mac address, so how does it elect Root port and Designated port?

sorry if i am wrong in this question!

Comment: Do a search on BPDU.

Comment: i searchd a lot, but unfortunately i could not find.

Comment: Bridges send messages to each other and can listen for them on a port, regardless of whether or not the port is passing traffic and learning MAC addresses.

Comment: but sir, on which basis switch select DP or RP in listening state?

Comment: That is based on the messages the bridges exchange. You didn't look very hard for BPDU: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_Protocol_Data_Unit

Answer (score 2):

Whenever a bridge comes up, it thinks it's the root, and it will send out BPDUs claiming that it is the root. It does this until it receives a BPDU with a better root, then it passes that on. While a bridge is not passing traffic, it is still listening to BPDUs from other bridges. After a certain time period, all the bridges will have heard BPDUs from the various bridges and determined which bridge really is the root and the best path to the root bridge.

A full explanation of spanning tree is far to large for this site.